# Arrays.Stream vs Stream.of

Tags: arrays, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Why Iam getting different value when iam using Arrays.stream and Stream.of ideally both should return same value

i/p:

```
int num[]= {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(num).count());
```

o/p:

```
4
```

i/p:

```
int num[]= {1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Stream.of(num).count());
```

o/p:

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the code of `Arrays.stream` and `Stream.of` to understand more:

```
public static IntStream stream(int[] array) {
    return stream(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

Arrays.stream in one of signatures take an `int[]` and split the value in this array for that you got 4.

But

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T t) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new Streams.StreamBuilderImpl<>(t), false);
}
```

took an Object of type T for that `int[]` is considered as one unity, so for example if you use:

```
Stream.of(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{4, 5}).count()
```

You will get 2.

---

to get the same result of `Arrays.stream` you can use `flatMapToInt` after the `of(..)`:

```
Stream.of(num2).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).count()
```

Comment: Or use `IntStream.of(...)`. But I consider `Arrays.stream` the idiomatic way to stream over an existing array.